# React : error TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: node.js, react-native, http-headers

I have used node js as server that just response some Json data.

```js
//https
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/key.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/cert.pem').toString();
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
var PORT = 18080;
var SSLPORT = 18081;

httpServer.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('HTTP Server is running on: http://localhost:%s', PORT);
});
httpsServer.listen(SSLPORT, function () {
    console.log('HTTPS Server is running on: https://localhost:%s', SSLPORT);
});

app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {

    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

    res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 ,'id':2,'title':3}))
    
});
```

My react code as following:

```js
let http_url = "https://localhost:18081/listUsers";
        fetch(http_url, init)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                this.setState({message: `${responseJson['id']} - ${responseJson['title']}`});
            })
            .catch(e => {console.log(`error ${e}`)});
```

I can get true json response result by input "https://localhost:18081/listUsers" in the chrome, but react emulator always tell me **"React : error TypeError: Network request failed".**
I thinks the reason maybe Node response header is not true. Who can give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: try console logging `responseJson` to see if there is any data there. Have you done that?

Comment: It is not work, always catch exception "error TypeError: Network request failed".

Comment: what is `init` supposed to be?

Comment: const init = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            // body: JSON.stringify({
            //
            // })
        };

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969333/react-native-fetch-request-failed-with-error-typeerror-network-request-faile). Your mobile device has its own ip address and is trying to connect to its own localhost and not the one that you started up on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed node side code like this ?

```
res.json({ a: 1 ,'id':2,'title':3});
```

I think you are passing data as a string. Requirement is json

Also first try with http:// if you got success results then after try with https://