# React native authentication using laravel backend API

Tags: javascript, react-native, laravel-api

I'm new to react-native. I currently try to set the login of react-native by using the Laravel API. The API that I used already tested and its work. But when I tried to put in the react-native, it shows the error while i called the API. 
The warning in the emulator is: 
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0):
TypeError: Network request failed

Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    TextInput,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Alert,
    AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';


export default class Login extends Component   {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        }
    };
    signup(){
        Actions.signup()
    }
    home(){
        Actions.home()
    }
    handleLogin = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8888/api/login',{
            method: 'POST',
            header:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
            })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {

            if (res.success === true){

                alert(res.message)

            }else{
                alert(res.message)
            }

           alert('test')
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Logo/>

                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                        underlineColorAndroid='0,0,0,0'
                        placeholder='Email'
                        placeholderTextColor= 'grey'
                        keyboardType= 'email-address'
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})}
                        onSubmitEditing={()=> this.password.focus()}
                    />

                    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                        underlineColorAndroid='0,0,0,0'
                        placeholder='Password'
                        placeholderTextColor= 'grey'
                        secureTextEntry= {true}
                        ref={(input) => this.password = input}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})}

                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleLogin}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>  

                <View style={styles.signupText}>
                    <Text>Don't have an account? </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.signup}>
                        <Text style={styles.signupButton}>Signup</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: What do you get if you add this to the end of the last `.then((res) =>` call

`.catch((e) => console.log('Error: ', e))`

Comment: can your put `headers` instead of `header` inside your fetch in handleLogin function.

Comment: @HY98 do let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: @AkhilNayak it doesn't work.

Comment: @speak u means 
`.then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
            
            if (res.success === true){
                
                alert(res.message)

            }else{
                alert(res.message)
            }
            
           alert('test')
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('Error: ', e))`
like this?

Comment: what error did you get after adding the catch statement?

Comment: Yes -- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises -- you should get an error logged instead of it failing completely.

Comment: Error: [TypeError: Network request failed]
this is what I get

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55834683/11380693

Comment: @AkhilNayak getting worst, After i add those code, can't even run-android

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

Comment: error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Comment: this is the error while i react-native run-android

Comment: could you run `cd android && gradlew clean` and then `cd.. && react-native run-android`

Comment: if it still doesn't work reset your code to last git push and I am sorry I can't help you further that.

Comment: I did. Then error come out

Comment: @AkhilNayak It's OK, thank you so much for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setup the adb and use the adb reverse command.

EXAMPLE

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:3333
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39108921/12988525